# What is the Alternative way of SQL Subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I need to show all patient's info with first Appointment Date. Here i attached my required info's image. Please have a look:

[image]

I solved it but i want to do it more efficiently. Here is my solution:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY p.Name) SINo,
       or1.PatientID                RegNo,
       p.Name                       PatientName,
       or1.DataHead                 Diagnosis,
       or1.AppointmentDate,
       'First Appointment Date' = (
           SELECT or2.AppointmentDate
           FROM   OPDConsultancyRepository AS or2
           WHERE  or2.OPDConsultancyRepositoryID = (
                      (
                          SELECT MIN(or3.OPDConsultancyRepositoryID)
                          FROM   OPDConsultancyRepository AS or3
                          WHERE  or3.DataType = 3
                                 AND or3.DoctorID = 2139 AND or3.PatientID=or1.PatientID
                          GROUP BY
                                 or3.PatientID
                      )
                  )
       )
FROM   OPDConsultancyRepository  AS or1
       INNER JOIN Patient        AS p
            ON  p.PatientID = or1.PatientID
WHERE  or1.DataType = 3
       AND or1.DoctorID = 2139
ORDER BY
       p.Name
```

Execution Plan:

[image]

`Above query needs 6 sec to produce output.` So any suggestion how i optimize it?

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Indexes are very important for performance. Include that DDL with the information @ZoharPeled requested.

Comment: The _execution plan_ is the place to start. See [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a way to include an execution plan in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a window function:

```
min(or1.AppointmentDate) over (partition by doctorid, datetype, patientid) as first_appointment_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT 
  ...
  [First Appointment Date] = 
    min(iif(or1.DataType = 3 and or1.DoctorID = 2139, or1.AppointmentDate, null))
      over(partition by or1.PatientID) 
  ...
```

Although I am wondering about the DoctorID, but trying to maintain your logic

It looks tempting to remove this part

> and or1.DoctorID = 2139

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful for you - you need to use Lead() and Lag() function within your inner query.

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/15/sql-server-introduction-to-lead-and-lag-analytic-functions-introduced-in-sql-server-2012/

Option - 2

If you use Self Join and with the use of CTE, you can achieve the same with great performance significance query.

Answer (score 0):

Without DDL and an execution plan it's impossible to say exactly what is slowing you down. One thing that's slowing you down for sure is that correlated subquery. Note this article: [Hidden RBAR: Triangular Joins](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/61539/) Second - lose that final `ORDER BY p.name` you don't need that. If the output must be sorted for display purposes, let the application handle it. Lastly, you should examine the execution plan for what is most expensive and add indexes where needed.

The way I would build this query it is first get it to a point where you have all your columns including all relevant patientID and the appointmentDate records.

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (patientId INT, appointmentDate DATE);
INSERT  @table VALUES (1,GETDATE()),(1,GETDATE()-3),(2,GETDATE()-10),(2,GETDATE()-20),
                      (3,GETDATE()-30),(4,GETDATE()-3),(4,GETDATE()),(4,GETDATE()-100);

SELECT t.patientId, t.appointmentDate FROM @table AS t;
```

You can probably turn the logic into an indexed view with the UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX being on patientID and appointmentDate. Then turn that query into a subquery and you have a few options:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (patientId INT, appointmentDate DATE);
INSERT  @table VALUES (1,GETDATE()),(1,GETDATE()-3),(2,GETDATE()-10),(2,GETDATE()-20),
                      (3,GETDATE()-30),(4,GETDATE()-3),(4,GETDATE()),(4,GETDATE()-100);

-- Option #1  -- GROUP BY + MIN
SELECT   t.patientId, MIN(t.appointmentDate)
FROM     @table AS t
GROUP BY t.patientId;

-- Option #2  -- Partitioned ROW_NUMBER() filtered for WHERE rn=1 in subquery
SELECT 
  d.patientId,
  d.appointmentDate
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    t.patientId, 
    t.appointmentDate, 
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.patientId ORDER BY appointmentDate)
  FROM @table AS t
) AS d
WHERE d.rn = 1;

-- Option #3  -- TOP (1) WITH TIES + ROW_NUMBER()
SELECT   TOP (1) WITH TIES t.*
FROM     @table AS t
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.patientId ORDER BY appointmentDate);
```